# Do you need to change an HTML documents ending to work with PHP

Tags: php, html

I've started delving into PHP and I've seen that PHP files have a ".php" ending. I was wondering how this works, if you can put HTML code into one of these files, and how one would usually use PHP to collect information, if they'd create a separate web page for the form or if they can just convert an HTML page into a PHP page.

Apologies if my question is a bit hard to understand, it's a bit hard to put to words what I want to know.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, as a general rule your php files needs to end with .php to be read as php files, however, you can configure your server to show .html in the url instead of .php

Answer (score 0):

You can put html in php files, for example:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

This file file will display on a browser the classic Hello World page!

The way to use php depends of what you're trying to do. Sometimes it will be mixed with html, sometimes no.

Answer (score 0):

PHP and HTML would be used in conjuction to create web pages. One can convert a HTML document to PHP in order to acheive more functionality as they are used for different things. PHP is a server side scripting language i.e. it facilitates communication between the user interface (the HTML & CSS) and the back-end server stuff (data). HTML is a markup language which on it's own does not communicate with the server, it is simply used to display static content on a page.

Together, they can be used to create dynamic web pages. One way to think of it is like this: HTML provides the content whereas PHP manipulates the content in order to provide functionality.

In other words, if we were building a house then HTML would be the bricks and mortar and PHP the plumbing, heating and electricity.

You can include HTML code in a PHP file however all PHP scripts must start with:

```
 <?php
 and end with
 ?>
```

Regarding your question on collecting information, PHP provides functions which enable form creation and binding to databases, take the following:

```
 <?php
    echo '<form method="post" action="">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user_name" /><br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="user_pass"><br/>
    Password again: <input type="password" name="user_pass_check"><br/>
    E-mail: <input type="email" name="user_email">
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>';
 ?>
```

This is an example of a simple form written in PHP to enable a user to log in, where HTML and PHP differ is that while you can create the same form in HTML, PHP gives you access to all sorts of nifty features such as performing data validation, security checks and database access.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a webserver sees a page ending in `.php` and has a PHP interpreter registered then it will pass the page to the interpreter.

The interpreter will pass any result back. If there's no PHP code in the page (e.g. there's only HTML) the interpreter will just pass the HTML back the way it gets it, but if you add a `<?php ... ?>` block the interpreter will evaluate the contents of that block and replace it with the result (e.g. if you do `<?php echo "Hello world" ?>` it will replace it with "Hello world").

That's just the short version.